# What is the proper format of the request 'body' in a Data Factory REST API POST?

Tags: sql-server, rest, post, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pull some data using Data Factory from a POST rest API endpoint. When I model it out in postman, everything works great and I get the data back in JSON format the data I wanted. (see clip)

[image: Postman]

When I try to convert this info into Data Factory, I'm going nowhere fast:

[image: Data Factory Setup]

I've searched and found the Request body formatted multiple ways:
eg1

> webServiceKey=xxxxxx&requestUserId=xxxx&apiReturnFormat=xxxx&appRequest=xxxx&reserveMinutes=xxxx&departmentId=xxxx&regionId=xx

eg2 - JSON like

> {"webServiceKey"="xxxxxx","requestUserId"="xxxx","companyId":"xxxx","apiReturnFormat":"xxxx","appRequest"="xxxx","reserveMinutes":"xxxx","departmentId":"xxxx","regionId":"xxx"}

I've also tried with '=' instead of ':' and a few other combinations. when I use combinations that look similar to eg1, I get access denied error message (on debug and preview). When I use eg2 (and similar), I usually get error messages like:

> Check if the data is in valid JSON object format. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: B. Path '', line 0, position 0.

The headers in postman are also in Data Factory.
Anyone know how to correctly format the keys in the ADF Request body so this pipeline pulls data?

Comment: Look at the raw request body in postman.

Comment: I have body key pairs under x-www-form-urlencodeed, but nothing in raw.

Comment: IPerhaps use Fiddler, etc to see it.  or read up on form encoding to learn how to construct the body.

Comment: thanks David. I'll try fiddler ... and get reading :)

Comment: It's possible you may have special characters in the json string data. `=` is not a valid JSON separator so for sure that will throw an error.  The parsing error is leading me to believe it's an encoding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had it right from the beginning. I needed to format the body like this:

```
webServiceKey=xxxxxx&requestUserId=xxxx&apiReturnFormat=xxxx&appRequest=xxxx&reserveMinutes=xxxx&departmentId=xxxx&regionId=xx
```

The issue was that the API admin told me that he entered all the IP addresses that I gave him into his whitelist (including my local IP), but he missed a few of the Azure DF East ranges. Once I realized and he cleaned up his whitelist, I was able to pull data from Data Factory.

Thanks for the suggestions,
John

Answer (score 0):

As per [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#type-properties) Json is supported for Both **request body** and **response body**. **Non-Json values are not supported in request body** and request body can be in the form of `String (or expression with resultType of string)`.

[image]

So, try to pas valid Json as key value pair in Request body as below.

```json
{"name":"test","salary":"123","age":"23"}
```

> Check if the data is in valid JSON object format. Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: B. Path '', line 0, position 0.

This error usually occurred when the **request body** and **response body** is in Non-Json Format.